# Jquery toggleclass for same classes separated

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

i have problem with toggleClass function for same classes separated

How to make it works for same .toglebox and same .slider separated..

Thanks in advance for any advice.

JS:

```
$('.togglebox').on('click', function() {
    $('.slider').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

HTML look like this:

```
<div class="containerslider">
     <div class="slider opened">
         <p>Lorep ipsum </p>
         <p class="slider_wiecej">
             <a href="/portfolio" target="_self" class="read_more_box_slider">more</a>
             <a class="togglebox"></a>
         </p>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="containerslider">
    <div class="slider opened">
         <p>Lorep ipsum </p>
         <p class="slider_wiecej">
             <a href="/portfolio" target="_self" class="read_more_box_slider">more</a>
             <a class="togglebox"></a>
         </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('.slider').toggleClass('opened closed');`

Answer (score 1):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) or [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents):

```
$('.togglebox').on('click', function() {
   $(this) //refer to clicked element
     .closest('.slider') //find nearest parent div with class 'slider'
     .toggleClass('opened closed');//toggle the class
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` object inside the function is what you need. Use this to find parent `.slider`

```js
$('.togglebox').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('div.slider').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

```css
.opened{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.closed{
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerslider">
     <div class="slider opened">
         <p>Lorep ipsum </p>
         <p class="slider_wiecej">
             <a href="/portfolio" target="_self" class="read_more_box_slider">more</a>
             <a class="togglebox">s</a>
         </p>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="containerslider">
    <div class="slider opened">
         <p>Lorep ipsum </p>
         <p class="slider_wiecej">
             <a href="/portfolio" target="_self" class="read_more_box_slider">more</a>
             <a class="togglebox">s</a>
         </p>
    </div>
</div>
```